# JDBC Error in RubyMine 5.4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jdbc, odbc, rubymine

I have a problem with ruby mine 5.4 an connection to my sqlite3 or mysql database.

There comes allways the same error msg:

```
Connection to Rails rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan-master: development failed: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer.main(RemoteJdbcServer.java:15)
```

Someone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is the full directory path where you've instructed RubyMine to download the JDBC driver? You can find the java call parameters in [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446). This issue can happen if the JDBC driver `.jar` file is located in a directory with non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the drivers following the steps in this page

**https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/8.0/configuring-a-db-data-source.html**

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the driver using IntelliJ "Data Source and Drivers" dialog.  In the screenshot below, where you see "Show License" in blue, previously that was "Download".  After clicking on "Download", it works.

[image: Data Source and Drivers > Sqlite (Xerial)]

I got to the "Data Source and Drivers" dialog by clicking on the "Data Source Properties" icon (db platter behind wrench) from the "Database" pane.

[image: Data Source Properties button in Database pane]